# Technical details of M3

Tags: hardware, cpu, apple-silicon

Is there any documentation available about technical differences between M1, M2 and M3? The only thing that I found is number of cores etc that apple tells us, 4.05 GHz maximum according to toms hardware, and some improvements in the GPUs (more flexible cache + ray tracing). Has anyone spotted anything else?